# Pretty statistical evaluation (min, max, avg, std)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, align, positioning

Is there a better way of formatting statistical values in continuous text than this?

```
The participants of the study were on average \num{33.5} years old (min=22, max=51, $\sigma$ =8.55, median=34).
```

I especially dislike the inconsistent representation of the symbols and the non-conformity of the equal signs within the brackets.

Comment: You need `...years old ($\mathrm{min} = 22$, $\mathrm{max} = 51$, $\sigma = 8.55$, $\mathrm{median} = 34$).` Alternatively, since some are text, you could also use `\text`.

Comment: Note that \min and \max can be used in math mode.  You can create new functions like \std using \DeclareMathOperator (page 19 of amsmath).